# Как получить домен сайта, на котором находимся в данный момент с помощью XPath?

Tags: xpath

**Первый вопрос:** 
На странице
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath
получить домен сайта, на котором находимся в данный момент.

С помощью XPath запроса (f12 и ctrl+f в инструментах разработчика google chrome).

Вопрос, как это сделать? Какой должен быть запрос?

**Второй вопрос:** 
На странице
https://www.google.com/search?q=xpath
собрать ссылку на каждый нечётный результат поиска, кроме первого и последнего.

Вопрос, как это сделать? Какой должен быть запрос?

Comment: Вам явно стоит ознакомиться с содержимым статьи по ссылке.

Comment: ознакомился, но возникли сложности)

Comment: Тут на самом деле даже непонятно, с чего вы решили, что с помощью XPath  можно получить домен сайта. Строго говоря, HTML страницы даже не обязательно являются валидными XML документами чтобы обращаться к ним посредством XPath.

Comment: Я решил, что это можно сделать, т.к. вопрос является заданием,на которое я не смог самостоятельно найти решение, поэтому  и задал его здесь. (задание на собесе)

Comment: Может это был вопрос просто на умение пользоваться инструментами разработчика в хроме? Тогда вам надо было набить там путь до какого-нибудь раздела, где есть адрес сайта чтобы его хром подсветил.

Comment: Нет, суть задания именно в том, как я описал, я ответил таким образом, поскольку не нашёл верного решения. //a[@href="/wiki/XPath"] Мне ответили: Не правильно, выражение выберет только ссылку на домен (и то лишь на этой странице). Нужно из ссылки получить домен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Домен сайта - ru.wikipedia.org. Если в консоли разработчика осуществить поиск этой строки по html, мы получим 15 совпадений. Тег link с атрибутом rel='canonical' содержит ссылку на саму страницу и есть на каждой странице википедии. Из этой строки с помощью функции substring можно извлечь домен:

substring((//link[@rel='canonical']/@href),9,16)

2) Получаем все ссылки результатов поиска, после чего пишем условия. Важно помнить о том, что условия в таком случае следует писать к уже готовым результатам запроса, то есть после круглых скобок - (запрос)[условия].

(//div[@class='r']/a/@href)[position() mod 2 > 0 and position() > 1 and position() < last()]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]